# How can I insert a Diazo theme parameter into some theme's class attribute?

Tags: xslt, parameters, attributes, plone, diazo

I want to replace a `class` tag attribute in my static theme on-the-fly, based on a theme parameter.

I tried this:

```
<replace attributes="class" css:theme=".conteudo">conteudo-$section</replace>
```

And this:

```
<replace css:theme=".conteudo">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">conteudo-$section</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
</replace>
```

And even this:

```
<xsl:template match="//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' conteudo ')]">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring((body/@class), 'section-', 0)" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Since I also have other rules referencing `.conteudo` element, it'd be also nice to get to know best practices on how to deal with those (after the desired transformation occurs), ie:

```
<replace
    css:content-children="#portal-column-content"
    css:theme-children=".conteudo" />
```

Comment: BTW, in `manifest.cfg`: section = python:" section-" + context.getPhysicalPath()[len(portal.getPhysicalPath()):][0]

Comment: To avoid AttributeError when calculating getPhysicalPath for resource requests (images, css, js) I changed my manifest.cfg to `section = python:not context_state.is_portal_root() and context_state.portlet_assignable() and context.getPhysicalPath()[len(portal.getPhysicalPath()):][0]`

Comment: The first part of the condition is there to avoid IndexError when context is site root.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference a variable just anywhere, but need to do so from an XPath expression.

You can avoid interfering with your replacement of the children nodes by inserting the attribute "before" the children.

Here's what I would try:

```
<before css:theme-children=".conteudo">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">conteudo-<xsl:value-of select="$section" /></xsl:attribute>
</before>
```

Comment: I reduced my rules to only the one in your answer. Even then it still gives me this error: * runtime error, element 'attribute' [77:0]
* xsl:attribute: Cannot add attributes to an element if children have been already added to the element. [0:0]

Answer (score 1):

As David said,  is the right way to do it.
And to set the attributes before the child elements, you have to do that:

```
<xsl:template match="//*[contains(@class, 'conteudo')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="$section" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='class')]|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--Identity template copies content forward -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I got an `Invalid expression [0:0]` error. More info:
`* compilation error, element 'apply-templates' [242:0]
* XSLT-apply-templates: could not compile select expression '@*[not(name()='class']|node()' [0:0]`. Full error message: http://pastebin.com/7DLP99xa

Comment: missing parenthesis: @*[not(name()='class')]|node(). I fix the answer.

Comment: The Invalid expression error is gone, but it still doesn't work. Did I have to combine this with David's suggestion? I tried but it failed with the same error: `Cannot add attributes to an element if children have been already added to the element`

Comment: I believe this doesn't work because <xsl:template match /> looks for the XPATH in the content and I'm trying to modify the theme. Is that it? How can I address the theme in the first line of your snippet? /cc @ebrehault

Comment: You always must set attributes before children: <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            blabla
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>